# Does the multiplicative group of GF(81) have a subgroup of order 9?

Tags: group-theory

$$|GF(81)^*| = |GF(81)\setminus \{0\}| = 81 - 1 = 80.$$
Since $GF(81)^*$ is cyclic, $|GF(81)^*|=n$ : for any divisor $d$ of $n,$ there's exactly one unique subgroup of $G$ of order $d.$
$9$ is not a divisor of $80,$ therefore, there is no subgroups of order $9.$

Would someone please help me with this and tell me whether my argumentation is correct?
Thank you!

Comment: Yes, $9\nmid 80{}{}{}$.

Comment: Worse, of course, this is a field of characteristic three, in which the polynomial $X^9-1$ has only the single root $1$ (of multiplicity nine).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's fine, by the Fundamental Theorem of cyclic groups, all subgroups have to divide the order of the cyclic group. Since you point out $9$ does not divide $80$ ,no such subgroup can exist.

Comment: It's just Lagrange's theorem.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown It's also the Fundamental Theorem of cyclic subgroups. I find the FT more basic than Lagrange. But you are right, it is just Lagrange.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct.   Actually you don't even need cyclicity.  You can just note $|\operatorname {GF}(81)^*|=80$ and apply Lagrange.